# Mcrypt install failed on ubuntu 14 and php55, plesk

Tags: ubuntu, plesk, mcrypt

Hej guys, when I try to install mcrypt as suggested I get a weird failure message, please have a look on the Image below.

[image].

Translation of the last line: Package cannot be found.

Has anyone an Idea? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by using. The hint using the universe repository failed.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to enable universe repository on your server to install this package.

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
```

Comment: Thanks! But even this failed: sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found. My server is brand new and it is the very first thing to add for me. I think there should be no conflicts...